# past simple or past perfect in this example

Tags: past-tense

The tree **was planted** by settlers who **founded** the city over 400 years ago.
What was done first? planted the tree or founded the city .
Would it be clearer if it was **had founded** because I suppose the foundation  was first. May be the date the tree was planted is not important or maybe both action were done almost at the same time

Comment: It's perfectly clear and natural as it stands. If the city had been destroyed by some catastrophe, you might prefer **had founded**. Either way, it's fine.

Comment: does founded mean that the city still exist and  that action is not completed

Comment: so what came first?

Comment: No. Both are possible. Native speakers mix them up all the time. The past perfect simply serves to emphasise the sequence of actions when that's the speaker's intention.

Comment: If  both meanings are possible the sentence is unclear so is it because in fact  we don't know what was done first (planted or founded)

Comment: or the writer did not want to link both action (no causality)

Answer (score 1):

I'd argue that the sentence intends to convey that the founders of the the city planted the tree. Given the 400-year time frame, it would be reasonable to believe that the founding and the tree planting both happened about 400 years ago.